# How do I uninstall Wine?

Tags: macos, wine

I installed Wine through a .pkg file, and I want to completely remove all traces of Wine.

I've searched around the internet, but I cannot find any way to uninstall wine if you've installed through a .pkg file.
I installed [this](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/macosx/download.html) one:
[image]

Can I just search Wine in Finder with show hidden files on, and delete all of the results that have to do with wine?

Comment: Go into applications folder while Wine's quit, then drag it into the trash and empty the trash?

Comment: @owlswipe I'm pretty sure Wine has some other files other than in the Applications folder, like for example .wine

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An uninstaller doesn't exist for this app (Wine Staging 2.0-rc3).

The pkg file itself only installs Wine Staging.app to /Applications, which is self-contained and you can simply delete it.

Almost anything else like user installed apps or libraries reside in the folder *$USER/.wine* and you can simply delete it. Some files are also added in *$USER/.local/*/* or *$USER/.config/*/*. The .local and .config folders may also be used by other apps like X11 or Wireshark. Here are some directories you may find preferences and other cruft.

```
~/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine-*
~/.local/share/applications/wine/
~/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine-*
~/Library/Application\ Support/Wine
```

Comment: You forget: `sudo rm -rf .wine` @klanomath

Comment: `sudo rm -rf ~/.wine` though; otherwise it will try to remove .wine from the root of the drive, which is not where it creates the directory at.

Comment: Even though, I've deleted all files (including WineHQ official recommendation and custom search at PC). However, when I launch new PlayOnMac it conflicts and opens empty windows of WINEHQ!